# PHP XML not parsing with SimpleXml

Tags: php, xml, xsd, simplexml, xml-namespaces

my xml not parsing, i have no idea why
First line of xml not parsing, but second line parsing good

I know about im missings whatever in code, but searched in google and not find correct answer for it

```
// this xml not work, with <soap:Envelope> tags

$string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<GetBrandsListResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<GetBrandsListResult>
<DocumentElement>
<BrandLst>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <Name>Audi</Name>
</BrandLst>
  <BrandLst>
    <ID>350</ID>
    <Name>BMW</Name>
  </BrandLst>
  </DocumentElement>
  </GetBrandsListResult>
  </GetBrandsListResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';

// but this xml works, without soap envelope tags

$string = '
<BrandLst>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <Name>Audi</Name>
</BrandLst>
';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
var_dump($xml);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with adding xpath and registerXPathNamespace

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('default', 'http://tempuri.org/');
$auto = $xml->xpath("//default:BrandLst");
```

Comment: in some cases you need to use html_entity_decode() function for correct parse string